# Getting the absent dates from attendance table in java-sql

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I'm using SQLite Manager. My problem is I want to take the absent dates from the attendance table which consists of att_date, intime, outtime and empNo. Attendance table consists only attendance dates.It doesn't consist absent dates. Is there a query to get the absent dates between two dates?

```
att_date   empNo  intime outtime
2017-03-01 624    8:30   17:00
2017-03-04 624    8:30    17:00
```

For example, I want the dates 2017-03-02, and 2017-03-03 as absent dates which are not in the attendance table. If someone could help in this,it would be appreciated
And I have tried below query to get the non attendance dates, but it doesn't give the required output.

```
SELECT  Cal_date
FROM   WorkingCalendar l 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT  1            
   FROM   Attendance i
   WHERE i.empNo='631'   and l.Cal_date = i.att_date and l.Cal_date between '2017-03-01' and '2017-03-04'
   );
```

Comment: Does the table always contain exactly two rows?

Comment: @CL...no more than two rows...

Comment: This can be done with a simple loop in Java. Why do you want it in SQL?

Comment: What are the contents of the `WorkingCalendar` table?